# Label as a link in symfony2 Form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I managed to create a label as a link using a form theme:

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-20 {{ form_errors(form)|trim ? 'has-error ' : '' }}">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.vars.id }}">
        {{ label|default(form_label(form, (form.vars.label|trans) ~ (form.vars.required ? '*':''), {'label_attr': { 'class' : 'control-label'}})) | raw }}
    </label>
    {{ form_widget(form, {'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
```

But now I'm displaying each field as individual and I can't manage to do it using this:

```
<label class="control-label">
    {{ label|default(form_label(form.terms,'Jaccepte les <a target="_blank" href="https://test">Conditions Générales de Vente</a> et les <a id="CGU">Conditions Générales dUtilisation</a>',{'label_attr': { 'class' : 'control-label'} } )) | raw }}
    {{ form_widget(form.terms,{'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} })  }}
</label>
```

Comment: You could achieve this without custom fields

Comment: Thanks but I really need to use custom fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correct you can use it like this (if `username` is the form element):

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ form.username.vars.label | trans }}
{% endautoescape %}
```